# Way to prevent razor from getting confused when using < > symbols

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to razor and I'm finding that it breaks a lot while typing (explanation follows)... It will tell me something is invalid (via errors) but then later the same exact code will work fine. It seems to have a major problem when using < > symbols (for generics). It will work until I start making changes again and then intellisense will break while I'm typing (when doing a lambda expression in this case). It then complains again about the brackets. My code is from a Telerik sample:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Order>().Name("Orders").Columns(c =>
  {
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderID);
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:d}").Title("Date");
      c.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
      c.Bound(p => p.Company).Title("Company");
      c.Bound(p => p.Email);
      c.Bound(p => p.Phone).Title("Phone");
      c.Bound(p => p.Total).Format("{0:c}");
      c.Bound(p => p.Approved);
  })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Read(a => a.Action("GetOrders", "Home"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("OrderDate").Descending())
        )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
 )
```

If I start to add ".Resizable(r => ...." under filterable the intellisense stops working and errors reoccur. I'm guess it's confused about the opening ( and the fact I'm typing another open brace for my lambda.

Should I be using a different approach. This makes razor pretty annoying if I keep losing intellisense. The only thing I could get to work was this, but it seems odd that I had to assign it to a variable first.

```
@{ var g = Html.Kendo().Grid<Order>().Name("Orders").Columns(c =>
  {
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderID);
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:d}").Title("Date");
      c.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
      c.Bound(p => p.Company).Title("Company");
      c.Bound(p => p.Email);
      c.Bound(p => p.Phone).Title("Phone");
      c.Bound(p => p.Total).Format("{0:c}");
      c.Bound(p => p.Approved);
  })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Read(a => a.Action("GetOrders", "Home"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("OrderDate").Descending())
        )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true));

    @g
}
```

Am I missing something or is this the correct approach to avoid intellisense problems?

Comment: Have you tried not using a leading bracket? E.g: `@Html.Kendo...`..?

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing that both with and without an outer wrapping brace and neither will work.